# mod-rewrite not getting value

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

RewriteRule ^department/([a-z]+)$ department.php?dep=$1

I can not get the value of dep when I use the forward slash in:
RewriteRule ^department/([a-z]+)$ department.php?dep=$1

However if I change it to:

RewriteRule ^department-([a-z]+)$ department.php?dep=$1

it works fine.

What's up with the mod rewrite when trying to mimic folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is probably due to [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it with [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options).

Comment: is it me or is that website down?

Comment: thank you.

i did 

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @user572909: You could also use `Options -MultiViews` to only disable MultiViews.